# Java play routing pass complex objects [Play framework 2.0]

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I've been experimenting with the Java Play Framework 2.0 for a few weeks now, but I am now struggling with the following:

How can I pass Java object from one Play template to another?

I can pass simple objects about no problem:

```
GET /Login/:email   controllers.Application.login(email:String)
```

With the following code in my controller:

```
public static Result login(String email) {

    //Do some stuff

    return ok("");
}
```

But what I need to be able to is something like this:

```
GET /Test/:user   controllers.Application.test(user:User)
```

With the following code in my controller:

```
public static Result test(User user) {

    //Do some stuff

    return ok("");
}
```

When I try compiling, I get the following error:

> not found: type User

Does anybody know what I need to do to get this working? Is it even possible? Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using basic (don't want to write 'ordinary') types as `routes params` is clean approach which will not cause a headache. For an example instead trying to send whole object it's better to send its `id` - most probably some kind of numeric type or unique `String` for an example if your user model has `id` of `Long` type you can just do it as easy as:

```
GET /Test/:userId   controllers.Application.test(userId: Long)
```

controller

```
public static Result test(Long userId) {
    User user = User.find.byId(userId);
    return ok("Now you're watching user: " + user.name);
}
```

Other useful sample are booleans which, instead passing it it's just easier use `0/1` `Int/int`  types (with default value set as `false`):

```
GET /set-admin/:userId    controllers.App.setAdmin(userId: Long, setTo: Int ?= 0)
```

or `true`

```
GET /set-admin/:userId    controllers.App.setAdmin(userId: Long, setTo: Int ?= 1)
```

controller

```
public static Result setAdmin(Long userId, int setTo) {
    User user = User.find.byId(userId);
    user.isAdmin = (setTo == 1); // of course isAdmin field of User model is type of Boolean
    user.update(id);
    return ok("User " + user.name + " is " + user.isAdmin);
}
```

so in template you can just make a link:

```
<a href='@routes.App.setAdmin(user.id, 1)'>Set as admin</a>
<a href='@routes.App.setAdmin(user.id, 0)'>Set as common user</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's really useful! As HTTP is stateless, is there a common practice for storing the object in the play applications memory somehow? I really want to avoid having to do multiple calls to the database to find the same object, as the database is likely to be hosted in a different geographical location to the application server. Thanks for your help!